# Can you make a resizable container of heterogenous values in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm looking to make a container like a `tuple` except that you can add or remove elements. For example, something like this:

```
Container con { 3, 3.0f, "foobar", std::string("batman") };

int x = con.get<int>(0); //access elements
con.push_back(500ull); //add elements
con.erase(con.begin() + x); //remove elements
```

I'm curious if something like this is possible.

Comment: Perhaps a `std::vector< std::variant<int,float,std::string> >` ?

Comment: or, less likely, `std::vector<std::any>`. Really depends on how you intent to use the container.

Comment: @user17732522 std::vector<std::any> is perfect for what I want to do. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard I really doubt that actually. It rarely makes sense to use a `std::any` and `std::vector<std::any>` is even less useful. It technically does what you are asking for in this question, but it can't be used properly as a vector, since you need to keep track of which element type is located at which vector position externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very slimmed down version of what we did on my team.  It was for a map, but it could easily be modified for vector. We did this before we migrated to C++17 where `std::any` and `std::variant` were available.

Declare a base "item" as follows:

```
struct ItemBase
{
    virtual ~ItemBase() = default; // need at least one virtual member
};
```

Then a template based derived class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Item: public ItemBase
{
    Item(const T& t) : _t(t) {};
    T _t;
};
```

Then your container is a vector (or any std:: collection class) of shared pointers to ItemBase instances:

```
struct Container
{
    typedef vector<shared_ptr<ItemBase>> ContainerVector;

    ContainerVector _vec;
 
    template <typename T>
    void Insert(const T& t)
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>(), "Don't allow raw pointers");
        auto spItem = make_shared<Item<T>>(t);
        _vec.insert(spItem);
    }

    template <typename T>
    const T& t Get(size_t index, const T& defaultValue = {})
    {
        if (index < container.size())
        {
            auto spItemBase = _vec[index];
            if (spItemBase && spItemBase.get()) 
            {
                Item<T>* pItem = dynamic_cast<Item<T>*>(spItemBase.get());
                if (pItem != nullptr)
                {
                    return pItem->_t;
                }
            }
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }

};
```

We disallowed inserting "raw" pointers to block someone from explicitly invoking `container.Insert("foo")` or any other pointer that had a volatile lifetime.  Forces the caller to use std::string, std::shared_ptr, or similar.

Fetching items out of the container with type checking is done by using a dynamic cast.  If there's an out of range or the type doesn't match,  you can handle that however you want such as throwing an exception.  In our case, we chose to return a "default value" or default initialized value.  You can modify to throw an exception or do something else.

Example:

```
Container container;
container.Insert(std::string("batman"));
container.Insert(3);
container.Insert(3.0);

std::string s = container.Get<std::string>(0);
int n = container.Get<int>(1);
double d = container.Get<double>(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C++17 you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/variant) to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using variant = std::variant<int, float, std::string>;
    std::vector<variant> array{3, 4.3f, "foobar", std::string("batman")};
    for(auto const& element: array) {
        std::visit([](auto const& element){
            std::cout << element << '\n';
        }, element);
    }
}
```

```
3
4.3
foobar
batman
```

Another option may be C++17 [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/any), but the use cases for this are very limited. `std::variant` is almost always the better solution!

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::any> array{3, 4.3f, "foobar", std::string("batman")};
    for(std::any const& element: array) {
        if(auto* ptr = std::any_cast<int>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "int: " << *ptr << '\n';
        } else if(auto* ptr = std::any_cast<float>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "float: " << *ptr << '\n';
        } else if(auto* ptr = std::any_cast<std::string>(&element)) {
            std::cout << "std:string: " << *ptr << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << "some other type without implemented handling\n";
        }
    }
}
```

```
int: 3
float: 4.3
some other type without implemented handling
std:string: batman
```